# Get count from query

Tags: jpa, criteria, entitymanager, named-query

I am using mysql 5.5 with openjpa 2.3.0.

I have entities with namedQueries (generated in netbeans - I would like to be able to use this), for example:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByGender", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.gender = :gender")
```

I am creating restfull aplication with paged results. I would like to return for every paged result the `Content-Range` header as `1-20/250` where 20 is pagesize, 250 total count.

I tried to create a query

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(1) FROM (" + namedQuery.toString() + ") as foo;");
```

where I could dynamicaly insert any named query and return the count without returning the result list -> it should be faster.

When I execute this, exception occurs

```
SQL state 42S22: Unknown column 'u' in 'field list'
```

Executing the query itself in entitymanager is ok.
Can I use the entity manager or criteria builder to create a query for counting results without returning the result list (and without writing for every namedQuery a count duplicate)? thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing JPQL with native queries. JPQL says SELECT u FROM entity u, SQL would be SELECT * FROM entity u or SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM entity u

You could write a JPQL named query counting the stuff, e.g. SELECT COUNT(u) FROM entity u. A getSingleResult() would then return an Object[], whose first element contains the count.

Not nice but working. Why do You have to query for the number anyway? Pagination means next = lastindex+pagesize. if next < lastindex+pagesize, the end is reached.

Comment: my queries can return many rows and I want to know the count before, at least to show  at the front-end (web, mobile) the number of all items returned - as I stated in question, seting the Content-Range... maybe can I transform the namedQuery to SQL query like "Select (*)..."?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me :) What I would do in your place is : select first page, pagesize+1 elements, if resultset == pagesize+1, then another page exists, so next page would be select from 2*pagesize, pagesize+1 elements and so on. Because You are only paginating, simply don't select more than a page and then decide of another pagination is possible. This enables You to keep only one page +1 element in heap.

Comment: yes, i am doing this by setting the first and max result, thats working fine.. but additionaly to showing the total results, I would like to count the 'last page' for example as (totalcount / pagesize)

Comment: Yeah I see. You could do it like google and tell the user that this are 25 of min. 50 hits :)

Comment: I managed to do it by nasty string joining of "Select Count(1)" and namedQuery.toString().substring(..indexOf("FROM")) so i get rid of the "Select u" part, but ist somehow hardcoded sollution :(.. thanks for your thoughts